# Why is my IEnumerable<T>.Where iterator not executing inside a using block while Async call?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, dapper

I'm sure this is not a Dapper issue however I am finding, in the following snippet, that the predicate supplied to the `Where` function is never executed.

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> GetProducts()
{
    using (var connection = await _connectionFactory.Create())
    {
        var products = await connection.QueryAsync<Product>("select * from Products");
        return products.Where(p => p.Active);
    }
}
```

However if I move the operation to outside the `using` it is executed.

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> GetProducts()
{
    var products = Enumerable.Empty<Product>();

    using (var connection = await _connectionFactory.Create())
    {
        products = await connection.QueryAsync<Product>("select * from Products");
    }

    return products.Where(p => p.Active);
}
```

Is there some sort of deferred execution going on?

Comment: You are aware that you ALWAYS pull ALL the projects and then filter in memory?

Comment: Yes @TomTom, I'm using a simpler query here for simplicity.

Comment: How are you calling `GetProducts`, since you are returning a `Task<IEnumerable<Product>>`, but then it needs to be executed, it is deferred execution, however in second one you have already allocated memory, `Enumerable.Empty<Product>()`, now there's no deferred execution any more

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, if you can make the following modification in the return statement:

`return products.Where(p => p.Active).ToList();`, **then it will work as expected**.

### Case 1:

Issue here is `Where` clause applied on the `IEnumerable<Product>` is deferred execution, which is returned wrapped up in the `Task` as follows `Task<IEnumerable<Product>>`, but now you need to run the `Task`, which shall execute the predicate too, Not sure how are you executing the Task or may be there's an issue with wrapping the deferred execution in this manner, but end result is predicate is not coming in effect as expected, even when its applied on the Dapper result, which is buffered by default (no-streaming)

### Case 2:

It works in the second case, since you are completely getting rid of deferred execution, `Enumerable.Empty<Product>()` is ensuring that memory is first allocated, so predicate is executed moment its applied there's no deferred execution. In fact predicate is any way applied outside the `using` block

---

In the Async method, you are disposing the connection with the `using` block, mostly since Dapper internally allocates memory that's why all the data is sent across, connection is then `disposed`, and predicate is never executed. I have similar sample, which doesn't rely on database connection and it works as expected, therefore we can deduce that connection dispose play a role here in predicate not executing. In second case predicate is applied outside `using` block, so connection dispose has no role and memory is already allocated.

---

### Sample Code (using LinqPad):

```
async Task Main()
{
    var result = await GetTest();   
    result.Dump();
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<Test>> GetTest()
{
    var value = await GetTestDb();
    return value.Where(x => x.Id == 1);
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<Test>> GetTestDb()
{
    return await Task.FromResult(
    new List<Test>
    {
        new Test{Id = 1, Name = "M"},
        new Test{Id = 2, Name = "S"}
    }
    );
}

public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

---

### Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your predicate is not actually working as predicate. It is simply a LINQ call.

```
return products.Where(p => p.Active);
```

When above line execute, `products` is already filled by all the rows from the table based on your query and `QueryAsync` call in earlier line.

Good thing about Dapper is that, it provides complete control of query writing to **you**. So, if you want to filter the records, why not write the query that way?

```
using(var connection = ....)
{
    var param = new DynamicParameters();
    param.Add("@Active", 1);
    var products = await connection.QueryAsync<Product>("select * from Products where Active = @Active", param);
    return products;
}
```

You should then remove the `products.Where` line.

---

**About actual problem you asked in question:**

I could not reproduce the problem. When I run following code to read the output in console application, it returns expected results.

```
DbDataReader dbDataReader = new DbDataReader();
IEnumerable<Product> activeProducts = dbDataReader.GetProducts().Result;
Console.WriteLine(activeProducts.Count());
```

Your method is little modified as below:

```
public class DbDataReader
{
    string connectionString = @"....";
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> GetProducts()
    {
        using(var connection = await GetOpenConnection())
        {
            var products = await connection.QueryAsync<Product>("select * from Products;WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'");
            return products.Where(p => p.Active);
        }
    }

    private async Task<SqlConnection> GetOpenConnection()
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();
        return sqlConnection;
    }
}
```

Note that I have intentionally delayed the `QueryAsync` call with `WAITFOR`.

Comment: My actual query is a lot larger and complex and for simplicity I chose an easier example. 

Can you expand on what you mean by this "Your predicate is not actually working as predicate"?

Comment: **"Your predicate is not actually working as predicate"** You are fetching all data in memory first. The `Where` (predicate) is not executing on SQL Server. Hence, it is not _predicate_ per say. First part of my answer explains how to do that.